# Python scrapping specs from psref stopped working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

So, I had a script that i used once in a while to get some computer specifications from lenovo.psref.com from time to time - its stopped working because they've changed their website design, them I made a new one, this time using bard+chatgpt to make sure im not doing something wrong.

when checking with bard, this script works and bard shows me the output I want to get, but when Im runing the script on pycharm, its runing without errors but doing nothing :(

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

# Create a Selenium WebDriver instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to the target page
driver.get('https://psref.lenovo.com/Detail/ThinkBook/ThinkBook_14s_Yoga_G2_IAP?M=21DM0004DS')

# Wait for the page to load
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# Get the page source
html = driver.page_source

# Create a BeautifulSoup object from the page source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Find all elements with the "rightvalue" class
rightvalue_divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='rightvalue')

# Extract the text from each element
rightvalue_text = [div.text.strip() for div in rightvalue_divs]

# Print the results
for text in rightvalue_text:
    print(text)

# Close the Selenium WebDriver instance
driver.quit()
```

it looks like the problem is before the loop because the "text" value is not printed at all

Comment: It does not print anything, because it does not find any elements. You should figure out how to create element queries by using Inspector in your web browser debug tools.

Comment: bard used this code and did find the elements, i also tried to give a 20 seconds "sleep" to inspect the page while the code is runing - and I can see the elements myself,
what do you mean "create element queries"?

Answer (score 0):

made it work without beautifulsoup:

```
   spec_contents = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'rightValue')))
    # Wait for the elements with the "rightvalue" class to become available

    spec_contents_text = [div.text.strip() for div in spec_contents]
```